# How to pass main object reference to its all low level modules in c++

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

When ever I create my main(Car) object, internally its creates low level modules one by one.

I am referring some function in main object in all internal object

Currently I am passing main object through function(Setter function in all class)

Some how I don't feel its good.could you suggest me some good design.

examlpe:

```
    car mainobject

   grid object                mainobject->getFIleName()
      vertex oject            mainobject->getFIleName()
          sub object1         mainobject->getFIleName()
          sub object2         mainobject->getFIleName()

   triangle object             mainobject->getFIleName()
        vertex oject            mainobject->getFIleName()
          sub object1           mainobject->getFIleName()
          sub object2            mainobject->getFIleName()

   canvas ojbect                mainobject->getFIleName()

   mesher oject                 mainobject->getFIleName()
         obj1                   mainobject->getFIleName()
         obj2                   mainobject->getFIleName()
         obj3                   mainobject->getFIleName()
```

I though of have static class. from static class I will get main object but i need to create multiple instance of car so I cant use static class

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for [component-based design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component-based_software_engineering)?

Comment: Maybe Flyweight pattern (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) will be useful for your. You can same general information in one class and all private in individual instances.

Comment: @Unick Thanks for replay. I cant trace based on index, thing are async. and I cant maintain index for all the low level classes its again overhead. I just want to pass my main object to all other object